# после hover() возвращать прежнее значение backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача такая при наведении на элемент менять его backgroundColor, после того как отводишь мышку, должно возвращаться старое значение backgroundColor.

```
$('td').hover(
function(){
  var a = $(this).prop('style');
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'navy');
},
 function(){
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', a.backgroundColor);
});
```

У меня не возвращает прежний цвет. В переменную сразу записывается цвет на который был изменен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `а` - локальная переменная. Логично, что другая функция о ней ничего не знает. Сохраняйте значение в сам элемент, при помощи метода `data()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('div').hover(
    function() {
      var el = $(this);
      el.data({color: el.css('backgroundColor')})
        .css('backgroundColor', 'navy');
    },
    function() {
      var el = $(this);
      el.css('backgroundColor', el.data('color'));
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
```

Но решение через псевдокласс CSS `:hover` значительно лучше

Answer (score 3):

Это на CSS делается, с помощью [псевдокласса hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```js
const originalBackgorund = js.style.backgroundColor;
js.onmouseover = e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
js.onmouseout = e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = originalBackgorund;
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
div:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id=js></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но так я знаю как сделать. Задача именно стоит сделать это через jQuery, не используя новые классы или css

Comment: @YURII обновил ответ

Comment: А можно как то при наведении определить текущий цвет элемента и записать в переменную, и ее дальше использовать?

Comment: @YURII обновил ответ. лучше делать это не при наведении (при каждом..), а заранее